# How can I map a django model to a python dataclass

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-dataclasses

There used to be a project in github that allowed you to map django models to python dataclasses, but it's gone now. You can still check it using the way back machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20201111163327/https://github.com/proofit404/mappers
https://web.archive.org/web/20201101163715/https://proofit404.github.io/mappers/

I'm trying to find another way to map django models to python dataclasses, but I can't seem to find any similar projects

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 (preferred way, support for custom datatypes, mapping both ways):

Check my answer here
[Using Python Dataclass in Django Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319176/using-python-dataclass-in-django-models/66690845#66690845)

### Solution 2:

It can be done using decorator implemented right here:

```
from django.db import models
from dataclasses import dataclass

# you can copy this decorator and use it or implement your own
def with_dataclass_mapper(dataclass):
    def wrapper(cls):
        def mapper(self):
            dataclass_kwargs = {}
            for field in dataclass.__dataclass_fields__:
                dataclass_kwargs[str(field)] = getattr(self, str(field))
            return dataclass(**dataclass_kwargs)
        # add 'map' method to class
        setattr(cls, 'map', mapper)
        return cls
    return wrapper
```

### Example:

```
@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    field1: str
    field2: str

@with_dataclass_mapper(MyDataclass)
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255)
    field2 = models.CharField(default="", max_length=255)

modelInstance = MyModel(field1="foo", field2="bar")
myDataclassInstance = modelInstance.map()
```

### Notice:

- This solution requires that Dataclass fields should be also defined in Model
- I only tested this solution using string fields.